# problems updating the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im not sure what is wrong with the code, it should update just 30 rows with the nulls but instead updates all the rows.

```
update nashville_housing_data
set property_address = coalesce(a.property_address,b.property_address)
from nashville_housing_data a
inner join nashville_housing_data b
on a.parcel_id = b.parcel_id 
and a.id_number <> b.id_number
where a.property_address is null
```

Comment: See [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html): Read section starting Notes "When a FROM clause is present, ...".

Answer (score 1):

That update is joining a and b, but not the target table.
Since there's no criteria for the target table it updates all records.

Here's an update that only updates the NULL addresses

```
update nashville_housing_data tgt
set property_address = src.property_address
from nashville_housing_data src
where src.parcel_id = tgt.parcel_id 
  and src.id_number != tgt.id_number
  and src.property_address is not null
  and tgt.property_address is null
```

However, if there are more addresses for the same parcel then it just picks one random address.

Here's a simple test for a method to update, but with some control over the value that's picked.

> ```
> create table test (id int primary key, x_id int, l char(1));
> insert into test (id, x_id, l) values
>   (1, 10, 'a'), (2, 20, null), (3, 30, 'c')
> , (4, 10, null), (5, 20,'e'), (6, 20, 'f');
> ```

> ```
> select * from test order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | x_id | l   
> -: | ---: | :---
>  1 |   10 | a   
>  2 |   20 | null
>  3 |   30 | c   
>  4 |   10 | null
>  5 |   20 | e   
>  6 |   20 | f
> ```

> ```
> select t1.*
> , t2.id as id2, t2.x_id as x_id2, t2.l as l2
> from test t1
> join test t2 
>   on t2.x_id = t1.x_id
> where t1.id <> t2.id
>   and t1.l is null
>   and t2.l is not null
> ```
>
> ```
> id | x_id | l    | id2 | x_id2 | l2
> -: | ---: | :--- | --: | ----: | :-
>  4 |   10 | null |   1 |    10 | a 
>  2 |   20 | null |   5 |    20 | e 
>  2 |   20 | null |   6 |    20 | f
> ```

Notice that for id 2 there are 2 possible values 'e' & 'f'

> ```
> update test tgt
> set l = q.l
> from (
>   select t1.id, t2.l
>   from test t1
>   join test t2
>     on t2.x_id = t1.x_id
>   where t2.id != t1.id
>     and t2.l is not null
>     and t1.l is null
>   order by row_number() -- pick the highest id
>            over (partition by t1.id order by t2.id desc)
>   fetch next 1 rows with ties
> ) q
> where tgt.id = q.id
> ```

> ```
> select * from test order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | x_id | l 
> -: | ---: | :-
>  1 |   10 | a 
>  2 |   20 | f 
>  3 |   30 | c 
>  4 |   10 | a 
>  5 |   20 | e 
>  6 |   20 | f
> ```

So id 2 was updated with the value of id 6

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4a8bac0c13d6c1491246e9708f58ae54)*